# Спецификаторы хранения extern,static,register,auto

Tags: c++, static

В чём суть каждого из спецификаторов?
И почему в данном коде я не могу получить доступ к переменной `i` ,так как по определению `static` хранит значение до конца программы в памяти.
И еще как мне с помощью `static` посчитать сколько раз вызывалась функция?

Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int foo() 
{
    static int i = 0;
    i++;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    cout << i;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ключевые слова `extern`, `static`, `register`, `auto` имеют различные значения, только `static` и `extern` говорят о хранении (причем оба подразумевают статическое хранение). `auto` перестал быть таковым с C++11 и теперь используется для других целей, `register` больше не используется. Зато добавили `thread_local`. Переменная `i` действительно будет хранить значение до конца программы, но ее область видимости ограничена функцией, в которой она объявлена. Но обращаться к ней непосредственно нет особого смысла, так вы все равно возвращаете ее значение. `cout << foo();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В С++ уже давно нет спецификаторов хранения `register` и `auto`. Спецификаторы хранения в С++ сводятся к: `static`, `thread_local`, `extern` и `mutable`.

Прямой доступ к переменной в С++ делается через ее идентификатор - имя. Доступиться к переменной по ее "короткому" идентификатору можно только изнутри *области видимости* этого идентификатора. Также при помощи оператора `::` можно доступаться к идентификаторам в других областях видимости. Однако оператор `::` не позволяет доступаться к идентификаторам, объявленным локально. В вашем случае идентификатор `i` объявлен локально, т.е. виден только внутри функции `foo`, поэтому доступиться к `i` за пределами `foo` вы не сможете.

То, что "`static` хранит значение до конца программы" на видимость идентификатора `i` никак не вляет: время жизни объекта и область видимости его идентификатора - совершенно не зависящие друг от друга понятия.

"Как с помощью static посчитать сколько раз вызывалась функция" фактически прекрасно проиллюстрировано вашим же примером

```
int main()
{
    cout << foo() << endl;
    cout << foo() << endl;
    cout << foo() << endl;
    cout << foo() << endl;
}
```

Comment: В очередной раз удивляете новыми словами :) «доступиться» ...